# Strange output when checking typeinfo of a string

Tags: c++, string, types, typeinfo

When checking the `typeinfo` of a String in c++, it returns a strange output `A19_c`, **what does the `A19_c` mean?**

When explicitly initialized as a referenced type string, it works find and returns an `Ss`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT */   

    std::string mystr = "I am a code monkey";
    cout << typeid(mystr).name() << endl;
    cout << typeid("I am a code monkey").name() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[out]:

```
Ss
A19_c
```

Comment: Array of 19 characters, maybe?

Comment: A _string literal_ is not an `std::string`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`type_info::name`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info/name) is not required to return anything human readable. It is an implementation-defined name. It isn't even required to be *unique*. So the exact meaning of it depends on the implementation. Also, you're not guaranteed to get `A19_c` from any other implementation.

Comment: but for boolean, characters and integers and doubles, I will still get `b`, `c`, `i` and `d`, right?

Comment: @alvas As stated, it is implementation defined.  There is no guarantee what name will come back, regardless of the types used.